# How to get column in Laravel junction table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I implemented Many-To-Many Eloquent relationship between **products** and **properties** by three table. ([like this](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many))

I can access product properties using the following code :

```
App\Product::find(1)->properties;
```

but how to get other column in junction table (such as "value" in this case)?

I have attached my database schema image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwD62.jpg)

Comment: This is a fairly well constructed question but, please provide more details on your tables and relationships.  Not quite enough to go on with this limited information.

Comment: You should look at Has Many Through, it doest exactly what you need: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any column that is not a foreign key is not added by default in the relationship object. You need to specify the extra columns you want with `withPivot`.

```
# App\Product model
public function properties()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(...)->withPivot('value');
}
```

To access the intermediate table, use `pivot->`

```
App\Product::find(1)->properties->pivot->value;
```